# Does a PC have a MAC address table?

Tags: mac-address, networking, windows

I have a network topology like this:

[image]

We know switch has MAC address table, but does the PC have MAC address table? I know PC have ARP table in Windows I can use `arp -a` display all the arp information of it.

if yes, how to show the MAC address table in Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless your PC is configured as a bridge, it does not have a MAC address table.

Since the PC does not forward frames from one interface to another, it has no need for a MAC table.

Comment: PC has ARP table instead of MAC table.

Comment: not really "instead". the ARP table is totally unrelated to the Mac address table of a switch.

Comment: Might be worth adding: even if a PC has multiple NICs, it uses the IP configuration and local routing to select between them, not any MAC addresses. (Unless it's bridging as in the answer.)

Answer (score -1):

Yes ! Every device in networking world has mac -address . Same as window pc . Every network interface card (NIC) has mac -address . If window PC has two NICs means it will have two mac-address . Not both mac-address are identical in world .

**For visibility of mac-address binded on NIC cards**

Go to windows R --->> go to command prompt ---->> type ipconfig ... This command displays

`Mac -address of NIc`
`IP address`
`Subnet mask`
`Default gateway`

Window pc don't have mac -address table . It has ARP table mapping ip address to mac -address

Go to cmd ---> type ARP -a to fetch ARP table in windows.